# Node js_CORS block access

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I'm trying to communicate with the front react at `localhost:3000` and the backend side nodeJS is `localhost:5000` but the problem I keep getting this message and I can't find a solution how to solve it

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NSheHsx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET-polling-xhr.js:268 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NShel1V net::ERR_FAILED
```

I tried every solution on the internet but without any chance

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://localhost:3000/",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

this is the `server.js`

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const loadRoutes = require("./routes/index");
const app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
const path = require("path");
let stream = require("./controllers/stream");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://localhost:3000/",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(fileUpload());

// database config
require("./config/db");

//require config
require("dotenv").config({
  path: "./config/config.env",
});

//config for only developement

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "developement") {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    })
  );
}
app.use(morgan("dev"));
//load all routes
loadRoutes(app);


io.of("/stream").on("connection", stream);
//---------------------------------------------
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    success: false,
    message: "Page Not found",
  });
});

//start our web server and socket.io server listening
server.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

changes that I made based on answer below but same error

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const loadRoutes = require("./routes/index");
const app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
const path = require("path");
let stream = require("./controllers/stream");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000/",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
// add this headers to your request and yow problems will be gone.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(fileUpload());

// database config
require("./config/db");

//require config
require("dotenv").config({
  path: "./config/config.env",
});

//config for only developement

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "developement") {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    })
  );
}
app.use(morgan("dev"));
//load all routes
//cors anwser2
app.option("*",cors())
    loadRoutes(app);
    

io.of("/stream").on("connection", stream);
//---------------------------------------------
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    success: false,
    message: "Page Not found",
  });
});

//start our web server and socket.io server listening
server.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

Any idea on solving this error ?

Comment: The code shown in the question has at least one error: It needs to have `origin: "https://localhost:3000"` — with no trailing slash — not `origin: "https://localhost:3000/"`. Origin values never have any path part — not even a trailing slash. And checking origin values is performed by determining if there’s an exact match — and  `https://localhost:3000` and `https://localhost:3000/` don’t exactly match (due to the trailing slash). I don’t guarantee you won’t still have a problem after making that fix — that change on its own might not be sufficient to fix the problem — but it’s necessary.

Comment: @sideshowbarker any other solution cause I tried it that but still not working

Answer (score -1):

have you already tried enabling PREFLIGH like described on 'cors' lib?
There is a section on the docs explaining about 'complex' requests that need to make a preflight request before making the actual request.

Here is a simple way to enable to test:

```
app.options('*', cors()) // include before declaring the route
```

I got this information from this section on the readme here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Tho it's not recomended using wildcard '*' in production, so be careful :)
hope I helped

Comment: thank you for your respond but same issue it doesn't work

Comment: can you edit to share how you are declaring the routes in loadRoutes.js?

Comment: there is also a way to use cors only in an specific route, I would give that a try also

Comment: @Nodegeek have you tryed removing the trailing slash ate the end of the origin url? I upvoted the comments explaining this error, seems like a fair reason for not working (url not matching because of an extra "/" at the end)

Answer (score -1):

yow broh, you need to add them `access-control` headers

at yow code before your routes add it to express.

also I see you have

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://localhost:3000/",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
```

your origin cannot be `"https://localhost:3000/"` in localhost change it to "http://localhost:3000/"

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const loadRoutes = require("./routes/index");
const app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
const path = require("path");
let stream = require("./controllers/stream");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://localhost:3000/",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
// add this headers to your request and yow problems will be gone.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(fileUpload());

// database config
require("./config/db");

//require config
require("dotenv").config({
  path: "./config/config.env",
});

//config for only developement

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "developement") {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    })
  );
}
app.use(morgan("dev"));
//load all routes
loadRoutes(app);


io.of("/stream").on("connection", stream);
//---------------------------------------------
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    success: false,
    message: "Page Not found",
  });
});

//start our web server and socket.io server listening
server.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: @Emesto please see changes on my question same result cors blocked my access

Comment: look you are importing `http` and your origin is `https` your corsOptions is validating your origin to be equals to `https://localhost:3000/` instead of been that one use
`http://localhost:3000` remove the last "/" and the "s" from "https"

Comment: I clicked on this URL `http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NShufAC` and i found this `{"code":5,"message":"Unsupported protocol version"}`

Comment: this is the message error also `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NShuqC8' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: well something else you can do is move yow 
```var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);```

to do bottom, express is like an onion, them middlewares are layers added on top of the previous and on your case you are creating a server, then on top of that you are adding stuff, but you need to add yow stuff ,then create the server

Comment: yes i mean, you can update the code, but why dont you just get rid of `corsOptions`  just use `app.use(cors())` take them ooptions out

Comment: i tried that see image same result https://ibb.co/L8YMTNZ

Comment: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/ look I found this, it can help

Comment: im checking it i will redo server js based on this bloc and I will get back to u

Comment: could it be possible that the problem with package .json cause I tested the front with another `server.js` in another project and it worked but when i try on this project it is blocked